# Scala xhtml attribute breaks because of a question mark

Tags: xhtml, scala, iframe, attributes

I had a problem with:

```
 <iframe id="iframe1" src='http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=MT&p=D&yr=2&mn=0&dy=0&id=p43321191731' width="300px" height="300px"></iframe>
```

in Lift web framework (Scala) version. I get:

```
Message: java.util.NoSuchElementException
scala.RandomAccessSeq$$anon$13.next(RandomAccessSeq.scala:165)
scala.xml.parsing.MarkupParser$class.normalizeAttributeValue(MarkupParser.scala:1191)
```

It turned out the question mark `?` in the iframe src attribute that caused this.
What can I do to fix this quickly?

Comment: I know nothing about Scala, but that's not valid HTML or even well-formed XML. All literal ampersands including those in URL attribute values need to be escaped to `&amp;`.

Comment: And the width and height attributes take integers or percentages, not CSS lengths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.mail-archive.com/liftweb@googlegroups.com/msg08961.html

The problem is the ampersand, need to escape it

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src='http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=MT&amp;p=D&amp;yr=2&amp;mn=0&amp;dy=0&amp;id=p43321191731' widt    h="300px" height="300px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape the '&' characters.

```
scala> <elem attr="a&amp;"/>
res0: scala.xml.Elem = <elem attr="a&amp;"></elem>
```

Or:

```
scala> val a = "a&"
a: java.lang.String = a&

scala> <elem attr={a}/>
res1: scala.xml.Elem = <elem attr="a&amp;"></elem>
```